# Get widest option width from a jquery mobile select menu

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery mobile page, with some select menu. In the select menu, I have options as usual.

For example:

- Please select one
- Compaq
- Hp
- Asus
- `

etc...

When I open the page, the width of the select menu is the with of the `Please select one`, and there is a little icon, an arrow down. When I change the option to `HP` for example, the select menu will be really small, (font sizes and all others remains), just the width of the whole select menu will be the width of the `HP` text  and the icon.

What I want to achive, is to get the longest text and set the width of the select menu fixed to that width.

In my case, this should be the `This is a longer text than others`

With an `$.(each, options).

Here is what I've tired:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (event, ui) {
    var options = $('.ui-content .parameters .ui-select option');
    var maxWidth = 0;
    $.each(options, function (idx, obj) {
        console.log($(obj).text());
        console.log($(obj).outerWidth());
        //console.log($(obj).text().outerWidth()); This is what I really need, 
        //but there is no function like this
    });

});
```

The problem is, I can not get the width of the longest text. Can somebody help me to how to earn this?

It's ok with `jQuery` or `CSS` too.

**NOTE:** I do not need the `length` of  the text, I need the `width` of the text.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to adjust a selection to a fixed width, when you don't use "data-inline=true", which sets the width to "auto", and when you put the selection in a container and give the container a width

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gunnar/snxmr0pw/)

**css**

```
#container {width:400px}
```

**html**

```
<div id="container" >
    <select id="selection">
        <option value="1">i'm short.</option>
        <option value="2">i'm kinda medium...</option>
        <option value="3">i'm large, or better: i'm huge!</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but none of them is good. First has no `data-inline` thats not an option for me. Fixed with also not an option, because, if somebody add a new element in admin panel, that could be more wide than others.

Second isn't good to, as you see, not wide as `I am huge`, etc...

Comment: But as I see, there are no solution like this for my problem. Forget it.